# Regular expression Jmeter - Conveting value

Tags: jquery, regex, httprequest

I want to convert commas in regular expression value into tilde

I have to extract rowversion value from following jquery response

```
7({"d":{"results":[{"RequestQuoteId":1043,"RowVersion":[0,0,0,0,0,2,39,50],"TenantId"
```

I have used regular expression :

```
"RowVersion":\[(.+?)\]  and got value 0,0,0,0,0,2,39,50
```

Now i have to pass the value `0,0,0,0,0,2,39,50` as `0~0~0~0~0~2~39~50` in the next request
How to convert ,(commas) into ~(tilde) symbol via regex

Is there any way out

Answer (score 0):

```
 var res = str.replace(/,/g,"~");
```

This should do it.

Comment: It would be great if you could elaborate it

Comment: there is a replace function .<urstring>.replace("to_be_replaced","by_this").You can use that.

Comment: the solution is nt wrkng :(

Comment: ${__javaScript(${Rowversion}.replaceAll(",","~"),Rowversion no)};

Comment: I have used the above javascript for replacing , with ~

Comment: cant say.Got less exposure to jquery.:(